Is APL supported on the new Echo Spot
I was building a test Alexa skill to show a image on a Echo Spot model that just came out earlier this month. I tested it on a APL Response editor and it seem to work fine. On the simulator, it had worked. But on the Echo Spot, it doesn't seem to work. I looked at the webhook, and it turned out that the device doesn't support APL presentation directive.
Is there a way how to show a image on a Alexa Skill on a new Echo Spot model?

No, Amazon team have confirmed the 2024 Echo Spot will not support APL. It will run your skill like an headless device and display its icon but that’s the only image you can get it to display.
